# (Nearly) Identical Jenkins projects, one works, one fails

Tags: git, jenkins, ant

I have two Jenkins projects that are identical except for the repo being used.  Jenkins is running an ant build for both and using different targets.

The two targets do literally the same thing except reference a different branch.  One project works and the other errors.

The failing project errors with this:

```
 [exec] bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
 [exec] error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
 [exec] fatal: could not read Password for 'https://****@git.ersp.net': No error
 [exec] Result: 128
```

I've looked this issue up and what I can find appears related to other utility tools being used such as Atom, Winpty, etc..  We are **not** using these but we **are** using bash.

It seems the issue stems from bash not being able to ask for a username and password however these are being supplied by Jenkins (both projects are the same).

I updated my credentials in Jenkins just to be sure that was not the issue.  The first project **continues to pass** and the **second continues to fail** and they use the same credentials.

**Ant Targets**

```
<!-- RELEASE GIT -->
<target name="update-release-git">      
    <exec executable="C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe">
        <arg value="-C" />
        <arg value="${testing-release}" />          
        <arg value="checkout" />
        <arg value="${BRANCH}" />
    </exec> 
    <exec executable="C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe">
        <arg value="-C" />
        <arg value="${testing-release}" />          
        <arg value="fetch" />
    </exec> 
</target>

<!-- EPIC1 GIT -->
<target name="update-epic1">
    <exec executable="C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe">
        <arg value="-C" />
        <arg value="${testing-epic1}" />            
        <arg value="checkout" />
        <arg value="${BRANCH}" />
    </exec> 
    <exec executable="C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe">
        <arg value="-C" />
        <arg value="${testing-epic1}" />            
        <arg value="fetch" />
    </exec> 
</target>
```

**EPIC1** works while **RELEASE** does not.  They are both clones of the same repo, they are just using different branches.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**Edit**
To clarify, the jobs are meant to be run independently.

Credential information is passed via Jenkins Credentials Manager.  Under **Source Code Management > Git**  you pick the repo url and then the credentials are a select option of the available credentials already added to Jenkins.

Comment: What happens if you change the order, first EPIC1 and the RELEASE? How did you pass the credentials to ANT?

Comment: Doesn't appear to have made a difference, same issue.  To clarify they do not run back to back, they are meant to be run independently.  I'll update the post with this and credential passing.

Answer (score 0):

You're always going to have a bad time if you incestuously mix your build script and your source control.

Let jenkins handle checking out from git. always. 
if you have your ant script mucking up your working copy you hamper jenkins' ability to display the changesets which in turn messes up the ability notify those that have committed to that build or since last success.  As well as confusion when someone makes a change to the build script on a branch (which won't work when the branch is changed after the script is started.

It may be easier to skip passwords and use ssh keys to auth.

Hopefully you'll be in a good place once you stop trying to exec out to git.